# Unity: How to change UI elements layout at runtime (i.e. change RectTransform)?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm building an app using Unity that should run on Telephone and Tablet. The UI should be layouted differently (i.e. the `RectTransform`s of some UI elements should have different values) depending on whether the app is running on a telephone or a tablet. In the end I will put a logic to detect on the startup of the app which case it is and consequently trigger the application of the respective saved layout configurations. I want to avoid having to build two different versions of the app.

**My idea so far is**:

- A `LayoutController` controls globally the saving and loading of the different layouts:

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class LayoutController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static LayoutController instance;
        public LayoutConfigurationDatabase layoutConfigurationDatabase;
        public string  currentLayoutName = "Default";

        private void Awake()
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        public void Load(string layoutName)
        {
            var objects = FindObjectsOfType<LayoutHelper>();
            foreach(var o in objects)
            {
                o.currentLayoutName = layoutName;
                layoutConfigurationDatabase.Get((RectTransform)o.transform, currentLayoutName);
            }
        }

        public void SaveAll()
        {
            var objects = FindObjectsOfType<LayoutHelper>();
            foreach (var o in objects)
            {
                layoutConfigurationDatabase.Put((RectTransform) o.transform, currentLayoutName);
            }

        }
    }
```

- The `LayoutConfigurationData` scriptable object saves `LayoutConfiguration`s for all relevant elements:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class LayoutConfiguration
    {
        public string layoutName;
        public RectTransform transform;
        public Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "LayoutConfigurationDatabase", menuName = "Data/LayoutConfigurationDatabase")]
    public class LayoutConfigurationDatabase : ScriptableObject
    {
        public List<LayoutConfiguration> data = new List<LayoutConfiguration>();

        public bool Put(RectTransform from, string layoutName)
        {
            var item = data.Find(i => i.transform == from && i.layoutName == layoutName);
            if(item != null)
            {
                data.Remove(item);
            }

            LayoutConfiguration configuration = new LayoutConfiguration() { transform = from, layoutName = layoutName };
            var type = from.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] fields = from.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                try
                {
                    var value = field.GetValue(from, null);
                    configuration.data[field.Name] = value;
                }
                catch(Exception){ }
            }

            data.Add(configuration);
            return true;
        }

        public bool Get(RectTransform to, string layoutName)
        {
            var configuration = data.Find(i => i.transform == to && i.layoutName == layoutName);
            if(configuration == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Cannot find configuration");
                return false;
            }
            PropertyInfo[] fields = to.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                if (configuration.data.ContainsKey(field.Name) && field.CanWrite && field.Name.ToLower() != "parent")
                    field.SetValue(to, configuration.data[field.Name], null);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

- Each element that has to behave differently gets the component `LayoutHelper`:

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class LayoutHelper : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string currentLayoutName;
        [HideInInspector]
        public string status = "";

        public void Save()
        {
            LayoutController.instance.layoutConfigurationDatabase.Put((RectTransform)transform, currentLayoutName);
            status = string.Format("Saved layout name {0}", currentLayoutName);
        }

        public void Load()
        {
            if (!LayoutController.instance.layoutConfigurationDatabase.Get((RectTransform) transform, currentLayoutName))
            {
                status = string.Format("Cannot load orientation {0}!", currentLayoutName);
            }
        }

        public void Set(string layoutName)
        {
            this.currentLayoutName = layoutName;
            Load();
        }
    }
```

**The problem**:
This only works as long as I don't change the scene. After a scene change the reference to the `RectTransform` of the UI element in the `LayoutConfiguration`s is always *Missing*.

**The questions**:
Is my idea conceptually possible? 
How can I make this work?

Comment: All elements are "re-created" after scene change, to prevent this you should use [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) method to mark which objects should preserve from scene to scene which is not ideal method for UI elements. I would recommend you to re-register each element at scene load time ( eg. on `Start`, `Awake` `OnEnable` etc. )

Comment: But how can I save the respective configurations for each element (during development)?

Comment: Easiest way IMHO would be to create some kind of global configuration, set this to `DontDestroyOnLoad` and then create prefab for specific scenes ( menu, playtime, pause, cutscene etc. ). Then after loading a scene just check which prefab should be created, load that prefab, configure it and track each changes. All of above actions should be manageable from some UI Management class which holds up mentioned global UI configuration.

Comment: This approach has the disadvantage that we duplicate the UIs, so whenever there is to add/remove an element it has to be done in multiple locations, which I wanted to avoid.